# statsmodels logistic regression type problems

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I'm trying to get the coefficients for a classification problem using statsmodels for python.

My code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Read a csv created with MS Excel
df = pd.read_csv("my_csv.csv", sep=';')

# 'target' is the variable to predict
y = df.pop('target')
df['ones'] = 1.0

logit = sm.Logit(y, df)
```

But when I try to run the regression it always fails by different reasons

```
result = logit.fit()
# numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
# Though, print(np.linalg.matrix_rank(df.values, tol=0.1)) returns max range
result = logit.fit('bfgs')
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'float'
result = logit.fit('nm')
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'float'
```

Am I doing anything wrong with the types? `df.describe()` works properly and I also tried to pass a float cast as `converters` argument to `read_csv`, with same result.

Am I likely to be having a ill-conditioning problem? how can I recognize if this is the case and tackle it?

**Edit**

CSV: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8K4OvvtLcJZU2FDQV81QXFDeUU

Comment: Not really possible to debug without a minimum working example. What's the type of y? Do you have any missing values in y or df? What version of statsmodels are you using? You may have an ill-conditioned problem. Why are you changing the `tol` to .1 in matrix_rank?

Comment: can you provide some sample data from your .csv file?

Comment: Added a link to CSV in the question. Answering the other questions: y is 0 or 1. No missing values. statsmodels-0.6.1. And I changed `tol` to have more confidence in the range being max.

Comment: Adding the `method` to the `fit` call fixed the issue with `'bfgs'` and `'nm'`. It's amazing how one can get so blind sometimes (though this time the answer from the library didn't help), thanks there!. For the `fit`call without method param, I don't quite understand: strong separation should be good for a classification problem. Plus, I normalized the data and it doesn't help.

Comment: Strong separation is good for classification and prediction of similar data. However, the parameter estimates are essentially not unique, and will not be very reliable in predicting new observations that are not strongly separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `dtype` problem.

The exception with `fit('bfgs')` is that the first argument is the `start_params` not the method. You should use keyword arguments `fit(method='bfgs')`.

The other two problems are that the explanatory variables are badly scaled (large values), and that there is strong separation, i.e. there are only very few observations with predicted probabilities not close to either zero or one.

The main problem is that we can do prediction in this model, but we don't have enough variation in the data to identify the parameters. Essentially, there are many linear combinations of the explanatory variables that would all fit and predict equally well, or almost as well.

The following is after zscoring the data `df2 = (df - df.mean()) / df.std()` before adding the constant, and after trying several optimization methods. Both `'bfgs'` and `'nm'` don't converge and stop with maximum iteration or maximum function evaluations has been exceeded.

The standard errors and the confidence interval for some parameters are very large.

```
>>> print(res.summary())
                           Logit Regression Results                           
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                 target   No. Observations:                  432
Model:                          Logit   Df Residuals:                      420
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                           11
Date:                Wed, 18 Feb 2015   Pseudo R-squ.:                  0.9522
Time:                        11:41:40   Log-Likelihood:                -12.411
converged:                      False   LL-Null:                       -259.88
                                        LLR p-value:                 3.858e-99
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x_1           23.6635     37.189      0.636      0.525       -49.225    96.552
x_2            7.0859   1953.900      0.004      0.997     -3822.487  3836.659
x_3           -1.8228      3.723     -0.490      0.624        -9.119     5.474
x_4           -2.2849     26.949     -0.085      0.932       -55.105    50.535
x_5           -0.3327   4.46e+08  -7.46e-10      1.000     -8.74e+08  8.74e+08
x_6            5.6617     30.437      0.186      0.852       -53.993    65.317
x_7           -2.2849   1.92e+08  -1.19e-08      1.000     -3.77e+08  3.77e+08
x_8           -9.4476     32.708     -0.289      0.773       -73.554    54.659
x_9            1.2125      2.092      0.580      0.562        -2.888     5.313
x_10           6.0331     16.780      0.360      0.719       -26.856    38.922
x_11          -3.7498      3.187     -1.177      0.239        -9.996     2.497
ones          -6.9048   4.87e+07  -1.42e-07      1.000     -9.54e+07  9.54e+07
==============================================================================
```

predicted probabilities are close to either zero or one for almost all observations

```
>>> probs = res.predict()
>>> ((probs > 1e-2) & (probs < 1 - 1e-2)).sum()
92
>>> ((probs > 1e-1) & (probs < 1 - 1e-1)).sum()
2
```